# Is mapping your TFS local workspace to C:\ a bad idea?

Tags: tfs

My small development team uses TFS2010 in a corporate setting, and just about everyone on the team has their TFS workspace mapped to a folder at the root level of their C: drive (e.g., **C:\TFS**).  From a security perspective, is this a bad idea?

I fear that another person in our organization could log onto our PCs and have read access to the uncompiled code and connection strings in there.  Would it be considered a best practice to map your TFS workspace to a subfolder in your user account's **Documents** folder, which non-administrators can't access?

My fellow teammates' original intent to house their workspace at that level of C: was to keep the mapped directory name simple, and to avoid problems with the directory and filename limitations in TFS (see [error TF14078](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337645%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) for complex projects.

Thanks!

Comment: So you grant network read access intentionally to the C drive root folder to everybody in the office, where you work? Why not block domain local logins on dev PCs to dev accounts? Or block domain users from browsing C:\TFS using NTFS permissions.

Comment: No, I didn't say anything about other users accessing the directory on the network.  I was suggesting that if another user logged onto my PC when I'm not around, they would by default be able to see anything in the C:\TFS directory, versus being blocked from accessing, say, %userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\.

Comment: So then hide the TFS folder and lock people out using NTFS permissions!

Comment: That's actually been my best solution so far, and one I was playing with this morning.  Feel free to add it below, and I'll mark it as the accepted answer!

Comment: Hi, I don't see it's bad idea, Why not, but of course it's not a best practice as you said

Comment: `C:\TFS` or `C:\Projects` is fine -- and it's required in some cases -- Visual Studio is TERRIBLE at long filename support. -- Your worry about connection strings though points at a deeper issue; the developers should not have direct access to secure information like production connection strings.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 - Yes, you're definitely right about developers shouldn't have access to production connection strings, but I don't think there's any good way around obscuring connection strings for dev or test environments when you're actually developing, is there?  (I'm asking as I'm several years removed from the job that prompted my original question here, so I'm mainly curious now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warren P's comment under my question was headed on the right track.  This depends on how your organization secures the folders under C:\ on your PC when a different individual logs onto it, but generally speaking, you can secure your a folder for your TFS workspace at the root level of C:\ by adjusting the folder security as follows:

- Remove the entry for **Authenticated Users**
- Add an entry with full access for your specific **network user account**
- Add an entry with full access for the system accounts **SYSTEM** and **IUSR** so that the .NET system accounts can also access it while you are doing local testing

(These notes are based on a Windows 7 PC, so the procedures for older versions of Windows might vary a bit)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you need to be careful about when mapping the TFS collection too far under the root of your drive is file name/path name length. The file name must be less than 260 characters and the file path must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: Yep, that's the error I pointed out above.  Probably a good thing to spell out the details on this page too, though.  Thanks!

Comment: And keep in mind some of those folders can get pretty deep; so having the root mapping be "C:\users\foobar\documents\blah\my projects" might be less than 260 characters, but it doesn't matter, because some items need to be 8 more folders deep (especially with Nuget and NPM, and such), and your build will fail if you try to do that (also spaces are bad juju as well).